# How to do typesafe remote procedure call (RPC) in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, rpc

When developing both the frontend and backend in Kotlin it's just weird that we have to bother with rest json apis to connect them.
Ideal would be the ability to define an interface

```
interface Api {
    fun sum(x: Int, y: Int): Int
}
```

Implement it on the server side.

And on the client side be able to call it as easy as

```
val api = RPCMagic<Api>
val result: Future<Int> = api.sum(2, 2)
```

Much like scala [autowire](https://github.com/lihaoyi/autowire) library does.

Answer (score 3):

At this time Kotlin provides no functionality for this, but it's on our medium-term roadmap (after 1.2).

Comment: It's been a while. Any update on the topic?

Comment: I'm interested in this future as well